# Shopify, How to get product json by Id using jQuery api call?

Tags: jquery, ajax, shopify

Currently, I am getting products if logged in to my Shopify store in the separate tab. But if logged out from the store then getting the authentication(Shopify API Authentication) error. I have product id only to fetch product JSON (I don't have product handle which is available globally to fetch product JSON). I want to fetch product using jQuery AJAX call. See the working snippet below:

```
var productId = "000000000";
jQuery.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: '/admin/products/' + productId + '.json',
    success: function(response) {
        console.log("Product Object: ", response);
    },
    error: function(error) {
        console.log("Error: "+ error);
    }
});
```

How can I get product JSON in javascript using jQuery without admin logging in?

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: You need to authenticate: https://help.shopify.com/api/getting-started/authentication

Comment: Thanks for your help. It's working in Chrome but getting 303 error in Firefox.  Do you have any idea?

Comment: You're going to have to use a [proxy](https://help.shopify.com/api/tutorials/application-proxies).  You can't just put your API Key and password in a javascript file because they'd be readable to anyone.

Comment: Yeah Scott, Thanks. BTW, I am using js-buy-SDK (with access token) and it's working fine in all browsers and I don't need to put my API Key and Password in the javascript file.
Thank you so much, Scott.

Answer (score 2):

If you *must* do this from jQuery, you may be able to use the [Storefront API](https://help.shopify.com/api/storefront-api), which is lightly authenticated. But you can't use the Admin API in jQuery - it requires a API Key and Password, which would then be visible to anyone viewing your script.  If you must use the Admin API, you will have to use an [application proxy](https://help.shopify.com/api/tutorials/application-proxies).

Answer (score 1):

```
jQuery.getJSON('/products/red-rain-coat.js', function(product) {
  alert('The title of this product is ' + product.title);
} );
```

Comment: Can you be more clear while answering a question. please visit and check [how to answer a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Please edit and add and explanation. Code-only answers undesireable and your answer is on a low-quality post review queue. One problem is when there are a lot of answers people are looking through to figure out which one they want it slows them down if they have to reverse engineer your code to try to understand what it does and how it fixes the problem.